# Sublime text 2 - zen coding change key binding

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I need the TAB to switch between highlights in my css snippets.

I'm using css snippets and #FFF+tab =>

I want to change zen-coding key biding from tab to CTRL+, (comma)
I've changed (the last line in default.sublime-keymap) from "tab" to "ctrl+,"
The new command works (ctrl+,) but I still have the tab transforming #FFF to a div.

HOW to completely remove the tab from zen-coding without affecting the TAB from Sublime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't know what I've did wrong the first time but now it works)

so do **change the key biding to zen-coding in sublime text 2** just change the last line in Preference > ZenCoding > Bidings > **default.sublime-keymap**

from
**"keys": ["tab"]**
to
**"keys": ["ctrl+,"]**

(or whatever new key you want)